# How do I get the price of something based on the date in a separate column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-finance, gs-vlookup

I want to get the price of BTC on a certain date.  Column A being this:

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDBTC","close","date")
```

Column B having the list of dates:

- B1 -  11/02/2018 00:00:00
- B2 - 12/02/2018 00:00:00
- etc.

How do I get this to work?

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDBTC","close","B1")
```

Didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:BTCUSD","close",B2),2,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TEXT(B1:B, "dd/mm/yyyy"), 
 {TEXT(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDBTC", "close", MIN(B1:B), MAX(B1:B)+1), "dd/mm/yyyy"), 
       GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDBTC", "close", MIN(B1:B), MAX(B1:B)+1)}, 4, 0)))
```

[image: 0]